# How to store a list in a map in c++?

Tags: c++, stl, std

EDIT:

In case you come across this, the confusion was with the xcode debugger and not the code itself.  The code is fine

---

New to C++ but not programming.

I don't understand why the values of this list aren't being saved when I insert them into a map.

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <list>
#include <map>

#include "Movie.h"
#include "Date.h"
#include "Cinema.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Cinema cinema;

    string name = "transformers";
    Movie * transformers = new Movie(name, 2018, 6, 10);
    list<int> times;
    times.push_front(1200);
    times.push_front(1600);

    cinema.addMovie(transformers, times);

    cinema.printShowTimes(transformers);

    return 0;
}
```

cinema.cpp

```
#include "Cinema.h"
#include "Movie.h"

using namespace std;

Cinema::Cinema() {
}

void Cinema::addMovie(Movie * movie, list<int> & movie_time) {
    running_movies.push_front(movie);
    movie_times.insert(pair< Movie *, list<int> >(movie, movie_time));
}

void Cinema::printShowTimes(Movie * movie) {
    MovieMap::iterator it = movie_times.find(movie);

    if(it != movie_times.end()) {
        list<int> times = it->second;
    }
}
```

cinema.h

```
#ifndef CINEMA_H
#define CINEMA_H

#include "Movie.h"
#include <list>
#include <map>

typedef std::map< Movie *, std::list<int> > MovieMap;
typedef std::list< Movie * > MovieList;

class Cinema
{
  public:
    Cinema();
    Cinema(Cinema &);
    void addMovie(Movie *, std::list<int> &);

    void movieRunningAt(Movie &, std::list<int> &);
    void printShowTimes(Movie *);

  private:
    MovieList running_movies;
    MovieMap movie_times;
};

#endif
```

It seems like my movie is being correctly saved but the list of times are just garbage values in printShowTimes, even though they exist in the addMovie function.

[image: breakpoint in code]

I have a feeling it has to do with pointers but I'm not very comfortable with them yet!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code works<sup>*</sup>.

Make your function print the values and you will see that you are going to get the desired output:

```
void printShowTimes(Movie * movie) {
    MovieMap::iterator it = movie_times.find(movie);

    if(it != movie_times.end()) {
        list<int> times = it->second;
        for (auto v : times)
            std::cout << v << "\n";
    }
}
```

---

Note that C++ offers [`std::unordered_map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map), which may feet your need ("query a movie and find its times"), since the ordering doesn't seem to matter.

---

*But it uses pointers in a disturbing way. Consider posting in [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Sure you can get the correct answer, thanks for the help.  So much for the debugger being useful..